# Opencart Copying Issues

Tags: php, opencart

In opencart 1.5.3.1 I am having this strange issue where the product copying function doesn't copy the data for additional images correctly. When I look in the database, it appears it has only copied the first letter of the product image path, and that is all.

Does anyone know of this problem, and a possible fix?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like these is something wrong with this code. I'm not sure why it's there, or what it does, because the copy function works fine without it.

If youre having similar issues, try commenting out this code in admin/model/catalog/product.php

```
        $data['product_image'] = array();

        $results = $this->getProductImages($product_id);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['product_image'][] = $result['image'];
        }
```

Comment: Never seen that bug before, but a quick check shows that the line above those already merges the images

`$data = array_merge($data, array('product_image' => $this->getProductImages($product_id)));`

The issue is that `$result['image']` should in fact just be `$result` though as you've pointed out, just removing those lines also works